# Does a perfect conductor has unlimited supply of charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

In Griffiths, it has been written that

A perfect conductor would be a material containing an unlimited supply of completely free charges.

My question is, how is the unlimited supply of charges possible? As Every material has a fixed amount of charges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean literally infinite. Just so many free charges that no current you can create will be limited by a lack. Your ability to positively charge the conductor by pulling electrons off will not be limited by a lack.

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E} $$ If there is a depletion of charge in any location, the conductivity decreases.

A perfect conductor is defined as

$$\sigma = \infty$$

This in reality, can not exist. There are finite charges  and thus any movement of electrons from a current density with divergence would cause the conductivity to decrease. Setting it at infinity always is just wrong.

This equation also says that $\vec{J} = \infty $ for a perfect conductor. This is also just wrong, perfect conductors arent described by ohms law, so any conclusions made from it are wrong. This value of J is normally the steady state solution, but there is no steady state for infinite conductance  hence for any non zero E field  it gives false results.